# How does this SQL TO_CHAR function work?

Tags: sql

I'm studying for SQL exam, and I see the following code as a correct answer in [the study-guide](https://dbasanthosh.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/1z0-051-s.pdf) ;

```
UPDATE promotions
SET promo_cost = promo_cost + 100
WHERE TO_CHAR(promo_end_date, 'yyyy'>'2000';
```

How does this code work ? I refer to The TO_CHAR part of it . Also is the missing parenthesis here:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(promo_end_date, 'yyyy') > '2000';
```

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided takes the date variable `promo_end_date` and the date format `'yyyy'` and returns a string in the format provided, so just the `'yyyy'` part of the date. 
So `TO_CHAR(promo_end_date, 'yyyy')` returns the year 4 digit year e.g. (2000, 2001, 1990, etc.)

The update statement should increase the promo_cost by 100 for all promos that have an end dat greater than 2000. Hope this helps.

You can try it out in Oracle SQL:

```
select TO_CHAR('01-JAN-99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual; --should return the string '01/01/1999'
select TO_CHAR('20-APR-15', 'dd/mm') from dual; --should return '04/20'
```

You should check the Oracle docs for this, all their built in functions are well documented: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, if It was typing mistaking, but you have missed `)`

```
UPDATE promotions
SET promo_cost = promo_cost + 100
WHERE TO_CHAR(promo_end_date, 'yyyy') > '2000';
```